# image.publish() via image transport

Tags: ros, image, publish, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have troubles to publish images via image_transport.

This is what I want to do:

```
    right_image_.header.frame_id = left_image_.header.frame_id = config_.frame_id;
    left_image_.header.stamp = right_image_.header.stamp=image->header.stamp;
    left_image_.height = right_image_.height=image->height;
    left_image_.width = right_image_.width=image->width;
    left_image_.encoding = right_image_.encoding = image->encoding;
    //Split image into left image and right image
    left_image_.step = right_image_.step = image->step;
    int image_size = image->height*image->step;
    left_image_.data.resize(image_size);
    right_image_.data.resize(image_size);
    memcpy(&right_image_.data[0], &image->data[0], image_size);     
    // the image of right camera is the first half of the deinterlaced image.
    memcpy(&left_image_.data[0], &image->data[image_size], image_size);     
    // the image of left camera is the second half of the de interlaced image.

    // Publish via image_transport
left_image_pub_.publish(left_image_, ci);
right_image_pub_.publish(right_image_, ci);
```

But publish method only admit

void publish(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image,
const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& info) const;

And I have only sensor_msgs::Image.

How can I convert from sensor_msgs::Image to sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr ??

Thanks a lot.

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55054/image.publish()-via-image-transport/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To publish an image, please allocate the shared pointer yourself.
I.e.

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

sensor_msgs::ImagePtr image = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::Image> ();
image->field = something; // fill your fields.
pub.publish (image);
```

Please prefer `std::copy` over `memcpy`. It has as efficient and behave properly on all C++ types unlike memcpy.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2013-02-18**:
Thank you Thomas. It works very well.